# Hibernate - Get Child Accounts from by parent Id

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Account")
public class AccountEntity{

    @Id
    private Id;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="AccountMap")
public class AccountMapEntity {
    
    @Id 
    private Long Id;

    private Long parentId;

    private Long childId;
}
```

How can I get the child Accounts by the parent Id? I would write a query for example

```
select acc from AccountEntity acc join AccountMapEntity map on acc.id = map.childId 
where map.parentId = :parentId;
```

How can I do this with @OneToMany/@ManyToOne annotations, so I wouldn't have to write a join in my query?

*Edited
I edited the query to make it obvious that I only want records from AccountEntity.

Answer (score 1):

Seems very simple too me

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AccountMap")
public class AccountMapEntity {
    
    @Id 
    private Long Id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parentId")
    private AccountEntity parent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="childId")
    private AccountEntity child;
}
```

Comment: How would the query look like?